# How to solve the error of inside setUser()?

Tags: html, angular

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {

  constructor() { }

  setUser(formData) {
       let fackresponce3 = {
          " errorCode " : "1",
          "errorMessage" : "User Created",
          "rowCount" : "30",
          "data" :{
            "token" : "abcd"
          }
       };
       let fackresponce1 = {
        " errorCode " : "0",
        "errorMessage" : "Some Error",
        "rowCount" : "30",
        "data" :{
          "token" : "abcd"
        }
     };
     return Observable.create(
        observer => {
          setTimeout ( () => {
             observer.next( fackresponce3)
          }
          ,2000)
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the error in question and any other details you can? This makes the question more useful for the community. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `of` operator to create a new observable. Then pipe that observable and use the `delay` operator instead of the setTimeout.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html

```
// backend.service.ts
import { of, delay, Observable } from 'rxjs';

export interface IResponse{
 data: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackendService {

  constructor() { }

  setUser(formData?:any): Observable<IResponse> {
      const fakeData = {} as IResponse;
     return of(fakeData).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
}
// note observables do not fire until they are subscribed to... so you can use it as follows




// app.component.ts

import { Component, Subscription, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private backendService: BackendService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.backendService
                               .setUser()
                               .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
     // also note to unsubscribe OnDestroy otherwise you will end up with a memory leak
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}



// app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ BackendService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```